# What is order of execution and how does it affect code?

Tags: functional-programming, theory, paradigms

I am trying to understand the difference between **functional programming** and **imperative programming** (and all other derivatives). However, I am stumped by one simple concept in which many websites and books never explain: what is an **order of execution**.

From what I understand, functional programming does not place importance on order of execution, while imperative programming does place a very high importance on it.

However, I do not understand this *order of importance*. I mean, if I multiplied and then divided an input number (`uno = input * 5000` followed by `dos = uno / 300`), would using a functional language mean that the program may execute the arithmetic operations in any way it pleases (without any regard to any rule, such as order of operations)? Where's the output predictability in functional programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of evaluation is the order the program expands functions into their bodies until you are left with primitives and the reduction of those to compute a result. Eg.

```
test(fun1(), fun2(), fun3());
```

Imagine this is an eager language, In order to apply `test` you have to have the values produced from fun1-3. In some languages the runtime is free to choose to expand `fun3` first, then `fun1`, and take `fun2` last. If no side effects are used it doesn't matter. If each one is displaying something on screen you suddenly have 6 different outcomes.

In functional programming you avoid side effects in most of your code. Without side effects the order of evaluation really doesn't matter.

When that said in all programming languages there are methods to force a particular order. In eager languages that have no evaluation order on arguments, like Scheme,  you nest the expressions in their own lambda forms.

```scm
((lambda (val1) 
  ((lambda (val2) 
    ((lambda (val3) (/ (* val1 val2) val3)) 
     expression3)) ; evaluated third
   expression2))   ; evaluated second
 expression1)      ; evaluated first
```

This is of course what `let*` does so you could write this:

```scm
(let* ((val1 expression1)
       (val2 expression2)
       (val3 expression3))
  (/ (* val1 val2) val3))
```

Haskell, which is a purely functional lazy evaluation language can do the exact same thing using monads. Then your function to produce the next value is dependant on some value returned on the previous. The chain makes the order of execution a steady path.

Now you don't want to decide the order where the order is not important. Then the compiler can decide and perhaps it ends up being done in parallel or do the shortest job first after constant folding.

Comment: Good explaination, but it still does not explain how having no order of execution would lead to a constant result (I.e. no side effects). I mean, if I wanted to multiply first followed by divide, wouldn't dividing first and multiplying later causes it to output another value?

Comment: @Skaty Actually with divide and multiply the result would be the same but Haskell has infix operator precedence so that it would do PEMDAS but it might do the same level elements in any order. In Scheme we parenthesise everything but things at the same level we have no power over the order.. like `(+ (square a) (square b))` we don't know which of the parts to be added are evaluated first, but we know the sum is done last. If we had output there we wouldn't know what came first, but we would have to program to make sure the output comes in the right order.

Comment: I realised that the result of my example is the same either way, after I posted it. Hmm, so without specifiying the order, the interpreter would be free to run the code on any order it deem fit. Hmm, I guess another question (for another Q&A) would be what's the point of low order of execution priority when programmers would still define an order of execution.

Answer (score 1):

**Order of Execution in Procedural vs Functional programs**

Procedural

> In a procedural language variables are assigned values which undergo
>   changes as the program executes. The values of expressions in the
>   program in turn depend on these variable values. Now, if order of
>   execution is not followed and variables are assigned values
>   out-of-turn then the values of expressions which use these variables
>   may not be correct as a side effect. Order of execution is thus
>   important in imperative languages to avoid such side-effects.

Functional

> In functional languages, as the variables are immutable, there are no
>   side effects of any changes done to the variables in some other part
>   of the code. Order of execution then becomes immaterial.Moreover, the
>   language designers use this freedom to build flexibility in execution
>   to achieve the best performance.

[reference](https://www.javabrahman.com/programming-principles/imperative-versus-functional-programming-paradigms-conceptual/)